# How should I interpolate between values in a logarithmic series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

What's the best way to interpolate between 2 values of a logrithmic series?

More specifically, I have a process where we encode values as $b = \text{floor}(\log(x, k))$. We discard the original values, and use b as a bucket for a bunch of statistics.

However, later I want to "reconstitute" an approximation of the original value(s) for things like graphing.

I could say the approximation of $x$ is $a = b ^ k$. However, this puts $x$ at the lowest value in the bucket.

I could say $a = (b + 0.5) ^ k$. But I think like that would put the approximation closer to the high value to to the low value, and I'm not sure that's right either.

Any ideas? Am I over-thinking this one?

(Also, did I tag this correctly? Let me know, or else just edit to fix it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would heavily depend on your distribution, and what you want the approximation for.

Some questions:

1. Is your data uniformly distributed over $[b^k, (b+1)^k]$? It likely isn't, and so you might want to bias your approximation in some direction to reflect this.
2. What do you mean by approximation? Do you want to find the average value of $x$ given that $b^k \leq x < (b+1)^k$? Or do you want the most likely value of $x$ given that it is in this range?

Comment: It's fair to assume the data is evenly distributed within a bucket. Really I just want a more-or-less representative value for visualization.

Comment: @RobY I would suggest using $(b+\frac{1}{2} ) ^k$ then. However, you should really question the reason for taking logs, which determines these buckets.

Comment: FYI we're using it to characterize data for machine learning. I tried to push a sigmoid function, but that was a little too exotic for the team. ;) We settled on log as a reasonable way to characterize the broad range of data we have. The problem is, as we're discovering, we lose precision for the big numbers -- which, as it turns out, are the ones we care about.